# Why is there an inconsistency between SE and SX to represent Space Exploration?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

I understand why SX might be chosen over SE, since SE is already a famous acronym for Stack Exchange, but I don't understand why SE and SX are both used for Space Exploration.

For example, in the title bar in the browser, both SpaceEx main and meta use "SE", but the chat uses "SX".

On the user page on main, the meta user button uses "SX". Same for the main user button on meta.

Is this an oversight?

Comment: I have it everywhere you describe as SE appear as SX to me. In fact, I've not seen SE repeat anywhere at all (tho I might have missed something, I didn't pay attention to every page I opened). Anyway, I suspect it's simply a matter of local cache. Try hitting CTRL+F5 and see it that helps.

Comment: @TildalWave I don't think that's the case because I'm experiencing this on several computers and browsers, I've cleared my cache recently on this computer, and I just tried CTRL+F5 to no effect.

Comment: You may wish to tag this as [design]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently there is only a design to represent a space exploration icon, in three versions.

#### Small favicon

[image: small]

which looks like

[image: small]

#### Touch icon

[image: medium]

which looks like

[image: medium]

#### Retina icon

[image: large]

which looks like

[image: large]

---

You should see all image to be identical to the "looks like" (with different spacing). If there is something different, it's likely caching.

Comment: Ok, I guess there's probably some weird regional caching going on in my area. Perhaps ISP related.

Comment: The caching issue finally cleared up.

Comment: eight years later, I'm not seeing some of these, the links return `404 - File or directory not found.` probably because it's eight years later and things have changed.